# New tag sit and go / SNG

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to add a new tag for sit and go related content ?
It may be called "sng" or "sit and go".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I added it to your sng/cash game question as well.

Thanks for the suggestion!